# 3 IP on one ethernet that not exist!

Tags: linux, centos, networking, network-interface

when i run "ip -d addr"  show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 promiscuity 0
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0
    inet x.x.x.1/23 brd xxxx scope global eth5
    inet6 xxxx/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxy brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0
    inet x.x.x.3/23 brd xxxx scope global eth7
    inet6 xxxxy scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxz brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0
    inet x.x.x.2/23 brd xxxx scope global eth6
    inet6 xxxxz/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eth8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether xxxxw brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0
    inet x.x.x.4/23 brd xxxx scope global eth8
    inet6 xxxxw/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

but when run `service --status-all` show:

```
IP x.x.x.1 already exists on eth0

IP x.x.x.3 already exists on eth0

IP x.x.x.4 already exists on eth0
```

i do not have `eth0`,
why?

Comment: Please edit question with full output of `ip -d addr`, we can't guess where all your network adapters come from...

Comment: @dirkt question  edited.